# Can you specify a not null column constraint from a select statement in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
select contains_null as no_more_null from [XXXXX] where contains_null is not null
```

I'd like to select the statement above into a new BigQuery table AND guarantee that new table's schema has REQUIRED for no_more_nulls. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` statement. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE dataset.my_new_table
(
  no_more_null INT64 NOT NULL
) AS
SELECT contains_null AS no_more_null
FROM dataset.my_old_table
WHERE contains_null IS NOT NULL;
```

For further reading, see the [DDL documentation for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language).

Comment: ahh. SQL n00b here. I was using the UI and selecting Destination Table. Thank you

Comment: @AndrewCassidy Accept the answer, please.

Comment: Do you know whether this be done with the standard Destination Table method?

Comment: You need to use CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT if you want to specify the NOT NULL constraint.